# Computer not recognizing native resolution of LG Monitor

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, resolution

I have an LG Flatron W3000H monitor which has a native resolution of 2560x1600 and connected it to a new Windows 10 PC with a "GeForce GTX 1650 Super" card. I then downloaded and installed the drivers from the LG website. The PC appears to recognize what monitor I have as it is listed in device manager:

[image]

However, when I go to Display Settings, it says that the "Recommended" resolution is 1280x800. I can select 2560x1600 but when I do so all that happens is that I see an upscaled 1280x800 image which looks horrid. I can confirm this by noting that the displayed Active Signal Resolution is only 1280x800

[image]

I had installed the LG drivers by right-clicking on the downloaded w3000h.inf file and selecting install. The installation process appeared to go without error. I noticed that the w3000h.inf file contained the line `HKR,,PreferredMode,,"2560,1600,59"` which I'm guessing *should* tell windows that the "recommended" resolution is 2560x1600.

Note that this question is not a repeat of [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1592661/cannot-change-active-signal-resolution) - This is a different monitor - indeed I purchased it precisely because I was despairing of ever getting the old monitor (with no available driver) to ever work. I thought that if I got a monitor from a well known brand with available drivers then my problems would be solved.

EDIT: The cable I am using has these connectors (see below) with the bottom one connected to the graphics card and the top connected to the monitor. I think that's Display Port to DVI-D. The cable is brand new.

[image]

Comment: How are you connecting? DP, HDMI etc. What version is your cable? If you don't know, then the first thing to do is get a new one to current standards.

Comment: @Tetsujin: See edit.

Comment: Ah, right. Chances are you're only getting single-link to DVI. See https://superuser.com/questions/332099/does-a-hdmi-to-dvi-dual-link-adapter-exist-i-dont-care-about-the-price which is for HDMI but has potentially relevant info then google "Displayport to dual link DVI"

Comment: Tada! I just tried the alternative DVI-D card output to DVI-D route with a different cable and everything worked!

Comment: Of course - if you have dual-link DVI-D to dual-link DVI-D then it will ;-)

Comment: @Tetsujin: If you put it as an answer instead of a comment then you can get the credit and I can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on guesswork & comments.

The existing DisplayPort to DVI is quite probably a single-link DVI connection.

The solution would be to replace with a DisplayPort to dual-link DVI…

… or far more simply, use a dual-link DVI-D to dual-link DVI-D instead, if you have the socket & cable readily available ;)